# 日付が変わると同時にでタップの回数をリセット

Tags: swift

日付が変わると同時にでタップの回数をリセットを行いたいのですが、どのようにやるかわかりません。
教えてください。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

タップ時に日付を覚えておいて、タップ時にその日付が変わっていればリセットすればいいかと。

Comment: オイラもこれに１票。タイマー等で 23:59 → 00:00 を検出するのは電池の無駄です。この案なら消費電力が増えないっす。

Answer (score 0):

「日付が変わると同時に」であれば１秒間隔で現在の日付を取得し、前回の日付と比較して変わっていればクリアとなるでしょう。消費電力を考えると、現在の時間により、定期的に確認する時間を可変する方法も考えられます。
タップしたときにクリアであればy_waiwaiさんの方法でいいと思います。